# Is there a file manager app for the sole purpose of enabling USB direct transfer of iPad storage files to a MacBooks?

Tags: macos, ipad, finder, software-recommendation, ipados

I'm using macOS Monterey 12.3.1 and iPadOS 15.4.1. iTunes has been deprecated. My files are locally on the "On my iPad" section in the Files app

After the "Trust MacBook" step on the iPad, I can navigate to the iPad from Finder as described in the [help article](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/guide/ipad/ipad32dd03cd/ipados).

However, I can't access the "On My iPad" section. I can only see the files listed under Chrome or other apps.

I don't have enough space on iCloud for this set of files and AirDrop would be too slow. It appears that the only way is to use a third party app into which I copy the "On My iPad" files, and then they will be visible in Finder:

[image: App Files Viewer]

**What is a trustworthy app on the App Store to achieve this function?**

Comment: Can you enable SMB sharing on the Mac and then access it from Files?

Comment: Related, regarding Airdrop throughput: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19517/what-is-the-transfer-speed-of-airdrop

Comment: @nohillside - why edit out the formatting from my question? It's easier to read that way...? Also no, AirDrop is slow in this scenario and will not work for me. SMB share is also a network-based solution - I just want to take advantage of the wired throughput, so an app would work best (barring built-in functionality into the OS).

Comment: A lot of people get confused if code formatting is used for non-code text. I don't know whether transfer via USB is even an option for apps (there might be no API for this), which is excluding network-based solutions may lead to no solution at all. How big are the files you want to transfer?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using iMazing for about seven years now. I wouldn't keep an iPhone without it. It's the grownups version of iPhone management, with all of the possibilities of Apple's file transfer and backup, even those for enterprise, available for end users in an attractive GUI. I believe there's a time limited trial.

iMazing is messing around with their licensing now, going to per device licensing but it's still affordable. It can also be picked up fairly regularly in some of the macOS bundles if you are patient.

Comment: I used PhoneView to perform bulk file transfers and they have a deal to convert a paid license to a discounted iMazing license. They are likely the best bet going forward for pro level support and features.

Comment: Good find (discounted license conversion). I have nothing bad to say about iMazing in a seven year love-hate relationship with iOS/iPadOS (like the devices but can't stand the locked down and inefficient file management). As I said, if it weren't for iMazing I wouldn't use iPhones. iPad I might use anyway (I don't ask much of my tablets, it's a reader and a video viewer).

Answer (score 1):

I do everything via Commander one, any file transfer, it's just something I've gotten used to over the years.Try to transfer "On My iPad" files to a location that can be accessed through Finder providing an this solution, for your file management needs.

Otherwise, if you've already found a solution, I'd be interested in hearing your feedback

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/downloads) for several years to extract files from iPads and iPhones. Works like a charm.

*Disclaimer: I have no financial or other connections to Macroplant LLC.*